# Join on the first id where the date is the same or in the past

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How can I join Table1 on Table2 on opid, only if the table1's date <= table2's date, AND it has no other matches?

Here are some example tables:

Table1

```
------------+-------+-----+
 date       | spend | opid|
------------+-------+-----+
 2019-07-05 | 5     |  1  |
------------+-------+-----+
 2019-07-07 | 4     |  2  |
------------+-------+-----+
 2019-07-08 | 6     |  2  |
------------+-------+-----+
```

Table2

```
+------------+-------+-----+
| date       | users | opid|
+------------+-------+-----+
| 2019-07-06 | 100   |  1  |
+------------+-------+-----+
| 2019-07-08 | 200   |  2  | 
+------------+-------+-----+
```

Expected Table

```
+------------+-------+-------+
| date       | spend | users |
+------------+-------+-------+
| 2019-07-05 | 10    | 100   |
+------------+-------+-------+
| 2019-07-07 | 4     | null  |
+------------+-------+-------+
| 2019-07-08 | 6     | 200   |
+------------+-------+-------+
```

So 7-July doesn't join, because 8-July has already joined.

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original version of the question.

I think you want a full join:

```
select t1.id, t1.date, t1.spend, t2.id as table2_id, t2.users
from table1 t1 full join
     table2 t2
     on t1.date = t2.date;
```

Comment: table2 is being joined on the latest (date) row in table1 with the same `id2`, which aren't necessarily the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try with inner join.

`select t1.id, t1.date, t1.spend, t2.id as table2_id, t2.users
from table1 t1 inner join
     table2 t2
     on t1.date <= t2.date;`